# How to show that union and intersection of min cuts in flow chart is also a min cut

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

The proof of this is everywhere skipped and said to be collorary of Ford-Fulkerson theorem.
It's usually something like:

Let $A$ and $B$ be low cuts of a flow chart. Then $A \cup B$ and $A \cap B$ are also min cuts.

Can anyone tell me how exactly this is proved or link me a proof please?

Regards, Raxel.

Comment: If you google on "min cut submodular function" you will find stuff that proves what you need, although I am not certain it will be in a form that is useful to you. (Which is why this is only a comment.)